# Android Cleaner Kill My Service

Tags: android, android-service

I creat new app Locker for Android but i have 1 problem my Lock Service I set All Receiver For Sleep, boot, Task removed, service can restart yourself but. Cleaner And Ram Booster Application Kill My Service And Cant Restart yourself. I already set ondestroy method Restarting but Ram Cleaner Not Call onDestroy.

Comment: Post code for your service, especially `onCreate()`, `onDestroy()`, `onStartCommand()` and your manifest

Comment: @DavidWasser Ram Cleaner/Booster Not Call onDestroy() calling forcing stop and not Wait for Callback. my problem not service lifecycle. Service normally run normal Way. but ram/cleaner/booster killing and not restarting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, This way

First Start FakeForeground,
Second Start Forground İn Service Same NOTIFICATION_ID,
After Stop Foreground Service Escape All Ram Booster/Cleaner

Comment: Hi, can you please give a little more detail for the answer.  I am having the same problem but don't understand what you did.  I hope you ended up with a foreground service.....my users really don't like them.  Thanks.